# Access Windows file from Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, cmd, openstreetmap

I am new to Python, and despite my searching, am unable how to properly access a file from a Python Script on Windows with Python 3. I am trying to use Mongosm to import openstreetmap OSM data into mongodb, but get an error when trying to access the file. How can I fix this? Thank you. According to the github instructions, all I need to do is `python insert_osm_data.py <OSM filename>` ([instructions found here](https://github.com/iandees/mongosm))

The error says:

```
    C:\Users\Jusitn>python C:\Users\Jusitn\Desktop\mongosm-master\insert_osm_data
 G:\OSM\planet-140430.osm
  File "C:\Users\Jusitn\Desktop\mongosm-master\insert_osm_data.py", line 160
    print 'node not found: '+ str(node)

SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: `C:\Users\Jusitn`? Is that a typo from typing the message in here? Or was that actually the path you used? I'm guessing it should say `Justin`. Also, that doesn't look like a complete exception. Did you copy the whole thing here?

Comment: My apologies, that was indeed a typo. I have also included the one line of the error that I omitted, where it says "SyntaxError". After that, it waits for me to once again input a command.

Answer (score 2):

`insert_osm_data.py` is intended to be used with Python 2, but you are apparently running it under Python 3. The easiest fix is to install and use a Python 2 interpreter (compared to rewriting the script for Python 3 compatibility).

Answer (score 1):

I myself is a beginner, but the much I am from the error, it looks like there is a syntax error in you file, as you are using python 3 you should use this : `print('node not found: '+ str(node))` in line 160 in you file insert_osm_data.py . In python 3 if you print statement is turned into a print() function.